# Can anyone help me on this Link issue:

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I am writing code for clicking link which looks as:

```
<a style="left: 520px; top: 340px; height: 24px; color: blue; position: absolute;" href="Login.aspx?iUserFlag=1">
```

Text: Sign in as different user?

I have written as:

```
Selenium.click(“link = Sign in as different user?”);
```

But i am unable to click, can anyone help on this?

HTML Snippet for this is

```
<A style="POSITION: absolute; HEIGHT: 24px; COLOR: blue; TOP: 340px; LEFT: 520px" href="http://kaizenblitz/Login.aspx?iUserFlag=1">Sign in as different user?</A>
```

the error message i got while executing is:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Element link = Sign in as different user? not found
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError(HttpCommandProcessor.java:109)
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.doCommand(HttpCommandProcessor.java:103)
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.click(DefaultSelenium.java:193)
at seleniumproject.gmail.main(gmail.java:19)
```

Can any one suggest me why i am unable to click the link?

Comment: Do you get an exception? ElementNotFound?

Comment: i got the the below error message: ERROR: Element link = Do you like to post one more? not found

Comment: Can you please add this error message to your orignal question and post the HTML snippet surrounding this link.

Comment: The stacktrace says: *ERROR: Element link = Do you like to post one more? not found*

Comment: sorry i have posted another similar error message, i have updated. please find

Comment: I am using IE browser,

Comment: You have to make sure that the page is fully loaded when you try to get that link.

Comment: i have used selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000"); statement before selenium.click("link = Sign in as different user?"); statement. but even then i am getting error.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on the line where you do `Selenium.click`. Is the page fully loaded when you get to the breakpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure that `Selenium` is your object, and not `selenium`.
2. My guess is that your issue is with the spacing.

Change `selenium.click("link = Sign in as different user")` to...

```
selenium.click("link=Sign in as different user")
```

Your test is looking for a link that has the text `" Sign in as different user"` (note the space at the beginning)

Comment: Thank you sircapsalot, It is working when i had removed the space at the begining.